# Gravitational waves interference lensing

Tags: interference, gravitational-waves, telescopes, gravitational-lensing

Is it possible to detect gravitational waves interference pattern in space, using a telescopes alone or a telescope coupled by gravitational lensing?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "possible". Possible n principle? Perhaps. Possible in practice with the modern equipment? Not at this time. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: NB: [gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) $\neq$ [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave); please be careful with usage of each.

Comment: Thanks, i've corrected that mistake and below is my response again.

Comment: I'll try to clarify: Observing gravitational waves interference using existing EM telescopes and not gravitational detectors such as LIGO. Observing interference patterns of gravitational waves, as they manifest themselves in EM image distortions or data distortions, of telescopes pointed at astronomical objects or telescopes pointed at astronomical objects via gravitational lensing.

Comment: Be it interference between: 1.GW of 2 separate sources, e.g. 2 sets of binary neutron stars, post merger 2.GW from a single source, e.g. from each of the 2 neutron stars in a binary system, before merger 3.GW from a source such as binary neutron stars, post merger, with the GW emanating from a source that creates the gravitational lensing, such as a black hole. 4.Other sources of GW interference, that pass the field of view of a telescope, pointed at an object or the field of view of a telescope, pointed at an object via gravitational lensing.